# Changing oc login password as a user

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

In our corporate environment, I'm given with an openshift container user account.

I can login into the cluster with the command

```
  oc login <cluster url>
  <username>
  <password>
```

The password here is a random generated one, and is made of complex characters. As a user, how can I change this password?

Is there any oc command that allows individual users to manage their account to change configurations like their own password?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenShift, [users are managed in an identity provider](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/manage_users.html), which means that OpenShift itself does not store any user credentials. That means that using `oc`, you cannot change your password and this needs to be done elsewhere.

In practice, OpenShift is often connected to an LDAP or managed via a HTPasswd file. So you'll need to check with your administrators how they configured the OpenShift cluster and need to change your password accordingly (either in the htpasswd file or in the connected LDAP).